# Should I use \unskip or \ignorespaces to mark up, and possibly hide, superfluous content?

Tags: spacing

I want to define a `\removable` command to mark up words, phrases, sentences, `\footnote`, and even whole paragraphs that I would consider superfluous and dispensable for the purposes of some day having to cut my paper down to meet a word limit.

```
\newif\ifremove
\newcommand\removable[1]{\ifremove\else #1\fi}
```

As it stands, though, when `\ifremove` comes out true, occurrences of `\removable` leave an additional whitespace behind.

```
This is \removable{clearly} right.
```

[image]

I guess I need to add either `\unskip` or `\ignorespaces` to it.

```
\newcommand\removable[1]{\ifremove\unskip       \else #1\fi}
\newcommand\removable[1]{\ifremove\ignorespaces \else #1\fi}
```

Considering that `\removable` is to be used not only within sentences but also at the beginning and end of paragraphs, in the middle of vertical mode, and all sorts of contexts, which one should I use: `\unskip` or `\ignorespaces`? Or maybe something else?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifremove
\newcommand\removable[1]{\ifremove\else#1\fi}
\removetrue    

\begin{document}

  This is \removable{clearly} right.

  \removable{This is ridiculously right.}

  That's it.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Honestly, I think this would be a huge distraction to me while writing, particularly when used in the middle of a sentence or paragraph. You would have to make sure that the text works both with and without the extra content; you are in effect writing two texts, not one. I don't imagine this to be any less work than just writing a good long version first, and worrying about abridging it later. When forced to condense a text, I usually look for a more effective overall arrangement, or a more concise rewording of verbose phrases; outright word deletions play only a minor part.

Comment: Did you try it? Neither will work as you want. I agree with @MichaelPalmer that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @cfr: I did, and both seem to work. And I disagree. It's been useful already. I just want to get rid of the additional whitespace without getting into trouble later.

Comment: @n.r. I tried both and both failed in some cases. One gave the 'wrong' output, although the output was right really as it was logical. The other gave a compilation error. I just created an example based on the cases you described wanting. But the output you want is illogical as you want to remove a space even though it is not in the scope of the removal command.

Comment: @cfr yes, the version in the OP gives a compilation error in vertical mode. An alternative expansion, at which I arrived in discussion with @egreg and @DavidCarlisle below, doesn't: `\ifvmode\else\unskip\fi`. As to what I'm looking for being illogical, that depends on what you mean by illogical. Surely, this has nothing to do with logic. All I want is a safe command that doesn't produce unwanted space, but allows me optionally to hide text *without having to modify my code*, either by deleting text, or commenting it out winthin paragraphs. I fail to see what can be illogical about that.

Comment: You don't want it not to add space. You want it to delete space which is otherwise there. It would be logical to have e.g. `this\remove{ and that}.` and want not to have a space after `this`. But you want `this \remove{and that}.` to not have a space after `\this` which is illogical because you've asked for a space.

Comment: No, I have not asked for any space. What I have asked is for a couple of words between `this` and a period to be removed. LaTeX is a *markup language*, it's **not** a typesetting system. And so, at the document level, the burden is on LaTeX to comply with what a text should look like, not the other way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it as follows. The LaTeX kernel defines `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` for making commands “transparent” to spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifremove
\removetrue    

\makeatletter
\newcommand\removable[1]{%
  \ifremove
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\@bsphack\@esphack}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Removed}

This is \removable{clearly} right.

\removable{This is ridiculously right.}

That's it.

\section{Shown}\removefalse

This is \removable{clearly} right.

\removable{This is ridiculously right.}

That's it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Thanks. But this still leaves a space before the a period in `This is \removable{clearly right}.` I could put an `\unskip` right before `\@bsphack`, but then it wouldn't work in vertical mode.

Comment: @n.r. That makes no sense: you have a space before the period anyway: the space should go inside the argument to `\removable`: `This is\removable{ clearly right}.`

Comment: @n.r. if you put an unskip before `\@bsphack` it wouldn't work _at all_ the whole point of the space hacks is that they do not add space if there was no space, but a space before or after or both results in one space in the output. `a \removed{} b` should make `a b` not `ab`

Comment: Hmm... so maybe two expansions? `\unskip` for horizontal mode, and `\@bsphack\@esphack` for vertical mode? (I actually have been using a `\removed` command, which expands to `\unskip`, for while that is handy for hiding in-paragraph content without having to delete code.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Maybe `\ifvmode\@bsphack\@esphack\else\unskip\fi`, instead of just `\@bsphack\@esphack`, can do the trick?

Comment: @n.r. no  `\@bsphack` does nothing useful in vmode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True. So now we have `\ifvmode\else\unskip\fi`, which seems, to me at least, to be doing a good job in hidding content without having to delete it from one's code, or comment it out. (Let me see if I can find a context where it doesn't work.)